# Asking questions with "where in something"

Tags: wh-questions

I wrote:

> Where in Islam is nationalism condemned?

Then I changed it to :

> Where in Islam is it said that nationalism is condemned?

I want to ask about an Islamic source that condemn "Nationalism". How can I say it with "where"?

Answer (score 1):

The collocation **where in {religion}** is understood to mean "where in *the central texts of* {religion}" and for that reason "is it said that..." is not needed and typically is not used, though it's not ungrammatical by any means.

> Where in Islam is nationalism condemned?
>
> Where in Islam is the concept of nationhood discussed?